# Wrong network at the transaction

Tags: tokens, gas, hardhat, etherscan, network

I transfered 1000 usdt to ethereum network mistakenly from bnb network and i lost them.   Can you help me with the solution to recover them please? i transfered them from binance to revolut

Answer (score 2):

The only entity that can help you with this is Revolut. If they have have access to address X on one EVM network they also, in theory, have access to it in any other EVM network.

Althought there's a big chance they won't help you because of various reasons, such as security concerns. But it's worth a try to ask them.